# Hide rows based on multiple checkbox values

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets, triggers

The project I am working on is to calculate costs of remaining sets in a mobile game. It has a spreadsheet with a list of all the sets, and checkboxes for all 5 pieces, Columns B:F. I want to include the option to hide all sets that are completed, so all Checkboxes are checked. This is done via another Checkbox, H16.

I have modified the Checkbox values to use Yes and No.

I have never used Google Apps Script before, and am very new to coding in general. I think what I need is, to use onEdit, then every time a cell is edited, check if H16 is TRUE, then scan through each row to check the B:F values. If all are true, hide that row. I don't know the best way to type that out, though.

Bonus points, I also want to include a reset checkbox, so when checked, set all values in B:F to false, and show the rows.
[Here is a link to the spreadsheet](https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1qx534MIueLl_yicPrc5YC5Ts6EVSCXPhsHt6hv51Wfs/edit?usp=sharing)

EDIT: My current GAS code, which isn't much because I don't know what I am doing:

```
function onEdit(e) {
  var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
  var sheet = ss.getSheets()[0];
  var maxSheet = 100;
  if(H16 == true)
  {
    for(i, i<=maxSheet, i = i + 1) {

    }
  } else {
    sheet.showRows(1, maxSheet);
  }

}
```

Comment: Can you share the Apps Script you've written so far, and maybe a read-only copy of your spreadsheet if possible, so that we can better understand what's going on?

Comment: Well, I haven't really written much in the Script so far, as I don't know what I am doing. I also thought that WAS a read-only copy I linked in the original post?

function onEdit(e) {
  var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
  var sheet = ss.getSheets()[0];
  var maxSheet = 100;
  if(H16 == true)
  {
    for(i, i<=maxSheet, i = i + 1) {

    }
  } else {
    sheet.showRows(1, maxSheet);
  }

}

Comment: Please provide an image of the sheet you speaking about.  Some of us do not follow links to spreadsheets and I'm one of them.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Hiding rows when all five columns are true**

This may not be exactly what you wish but I think it's close.  I did not use yes and no values because it's easier for me to leave it true false but you can change that.  I'm using Sheet0 and you can change that as well.  I used less rows so you can also change that.  But the basic idea is that when H16 is clicked it hides rows that have all five columns checked.

Code:

```
function onEdit(e) {
  e.source.toast('entry');//debug
  const sh = e.range.getSheet();
  const sr = 2;//data start row
  const lr = 15;//last row of data
  sh.getRange('K1').setValue(JSON.stringify(e));//debug
  if(sh.getName() == "Sheet0" && e.range.columnStart == 8 && e.range.rowStart == 16 & e.value == "TRUE" ) {
    e.source.toast('past if');//debug
    e.range.setValue("FALSE");
    let vs = sh.getRange(sr,2,lr - sr + 1, 5).getValues();
    vs.forEach((r,i) => {
       if(r[0] && r[1] && r[2] && r[3] && r[4]) {
         e.source.toast(`Row: ${sr + i}`);//debug
         sh.hideRows(sr + i);
       }
    });
  }
}
```

Image of Sheet0:

[image]

I use K1 to provide me with the event object while I debug the script.  And I also use the e.source.toast in several location to get an idea of what is going on.

Animation:

[image]

[an incomplete description of the event object](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/triggers/events?hl=en#edit)

You can get a better understanding of the event object by using the JSON.stringify code as show in my example.

Most new people want to run the code from the script editor so I'll tell upfront that unless you provide the event object to populate the e then it's not going to work.  Just copy and past it and get you unique stuff set like sheet name and data space and then proceed to edit the page and figure out how it works.

Comment: Thank you so much Cooper! While it is not 100% what I was looking for, it will work in this scenario.
That said, I cannot get the code to work within my project. I changed the "TRUE" and "FALSE" in your code to match my Yes/No Values, and changed the sh.getName to "Main", but it won't hide the rows. I clearly see it working in your animation, so I will keep tinkering, but wanted to see if there might be something obvious I have missed.
EDIT:

Comment: I found a single Ampersand in Line 12, making it double allowed the lines to be hidden, but it hid any row. I changed Line 12 to the following, and now it works as intended. Thanks for your help!
       if(r[0] == "Yes" && r[1] == "Yes" && r[2] == "Yes" && r[3] == "Yes" && r[4] == "Yes") {

Comment: I'll be happy to help you tommorow.  I had minor surgery today and I'm still recovering

Comment: Yeah I meant to tell you I just used the standard checkboxes which are true/false